# Developing alternative UI for Android. Which way I should go?

Tags: android, animation, android-layout

I am developing an App for Android, in which I need an UI that requires following:

1. Redraw at least 10fps
2. Buttons on screen, but not in rectangular shape
3. The whole screen (or at least the background, if its too heavy for the system) need to do some 'porter-duff' masking before render, on-the-fly

I currently figured out two way to go, both have cons & pros:

1. Start off from existing View - ViewGroup in the framework. Overriding onDraw to add the masking to it. This is easier to implement, but I am not sure if calling 'invalidate' that often will cause any trouble?
2. Build an alternative View - ViewGroup structure, and do the rendering in SurfaceView. But then I realize I turn up a structure that looks quite close to the existing one in framework, which I feel doing something almost the same with the framework.

Any suggestion?

(ps. in either way, I am not sure how should I catch the button 'click' event, which is in irregular shape)

Comment: Why not use opengl? The views really weren't meant for refreshing that often

Comment: OpenGL seems overkill for such a 2D scenario, and over complicated. I actually tested onDraw -> invalidate on a View, and it's still fine with about 57ms per frame, with my full screen porter-duff. Moreover, SurfaceView is designed to refresh: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html

Comment: Falmarri, how do you think any animation in Android happens at all? Of course they're meant for refreshing that often. They frequently are tasked with refreshing much more often than that.

Answer (score 0):

The button is easy.  Just add a Button view to your layout and use XML to define your own custom image.

```
android:background="@drawable/my_button_background"
```

The boundary gets automatically defined as the bounds of the drawable.  Simple and easy.

Comment: I did a test before. The appearance, yes, could be irregular. But, the hit region is still the rectangular boundary. For example, if you make a tile of buttons of hexagon, it may not work as expected once you click on it.